# Is infinity a solution of the equation $3x = 6x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can I say infinity is a solution of the equation $3x = 6x$ as both $3 \infty$ and $6 \infty$ will be equal to $\infty$?

If so, how come a linear equation in 1 variable have more than two solutions ($0$ and $\infty$, here)?

Comment: infinity is not a real number

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a basic algebra class, no, because you're working with the real numbers.  That is to say, the solution set of an equation $3x=6x$ is given by $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:3x=6x\}$.  However, $\infty$ is not a real number.

There is an extension of the real numbers called, unsurprisingly, the *extended real number line*, which contains the reals together with $-\infty$ and $\infty$.  And there are some limited arithmetic operations you can do with those.  In particular, you have $3*-\infty=6*-\infty$ and $3*\infty=6*\infty$.  So, $\{0,\pm\infty\}$ is the solution set to $3x=6x$ over the extended reals.  But typically, nobody cares about such things unless they're trying to be cute.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity is not a number, thus, it is not true that the equation has two solutions in the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "manage" $\infty$ always *in the limit*.

If your assertion was true, it would mean that given $0 <\delta $ you can always find $M$ such that for $M<x$ you get $|3x-6x| < \delta$, which clearly is not.

Viewing that geometrically ( projective plane), the lines $y= 3x, \; y=6x$ are not parallel, so they do not have the same *point at infinity*.